# UIScrollView and two overlapped UIImage of the same size not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios9, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

The view structure I'm trying to achieve is very simple: Two `UIImage` on top of each other inside a `UIScrollView`. The aim is that the user can load an image -let's call it `A`- and then make a change (eg. blur it) and these changes get rendered in image `B` which sits exactly on top of `A`. I can then fade `B` in/out to show the before and after.

When I set up `A` inside the `UIScrollView`, it scrolls perfectly. When I add `B` it doesn't scroll anymore. **I'd like to have both scrolling in tandem.**

I'm only using Interface Builder and I'm adding these 4 constraints to all elements, that is, the `UIScrollView` and both `UIImage`. IB is **not** complaining about any auto-layout missing or ambiguous rules.

[image]

*I have no other elements on my controller nor any views added programmatically (in fact this is an empty test project I created solely to debug this issue)*

Edit - Added view hierarchy image:

[image]

Comment: Have you double checked the constraints themselves to make sure each image is constrained to what you want it to be?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I think so. I've updated the question with a screenshot showing all the image constraints.

Comment: The constraints you described worked fine for me. Also pinning "Original Image View's" edges then aligning Original and Filtered centers x and y and setting Original and Filtered height and width equal to each other worked.

Comment: Is there more of the view hierarchy below your image? I tried setting up a scrollview with one imageview and it's giving me problems